# WPF application crashes on .Net 3.0 platforms

Tags: .net, wpf, c++-cli

I’m in the process of replacing the GUI of an existing C++ project to WPF.
This made me learn some C# and have a first look at .Net.
I chose compiling to target **.Net 3.0** so that all machines from Vista SP2 up will be able to run my application.
This makes the installation requirements unambiguous and shorten the installation time.
I develop on a VS2012 on a Windows 8 machine (x64).

The code consists of Pure C++, C++/CLI glue and C#/XAML code for WPF.
The application runs fine (Release configuration) on my development machine and on a Vista (x32) machine with .Net 4.5.1 installed.

It crashes on Windows 7 (x64/x32) machines and on Vista SP2 machines with .Net 3.0/3.5
I isolated the crash to the point where the pure C++ loads the C++/CLI glue DLL file.

From Dependency Walker (running Profile) on a Windows 7 machine:

```
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorrc.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE) called from "MSCORWKS.DLL" at address 0x690603E5. Mapped "MSCORRC.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x007B0001.   
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorrc.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE) returned 0x007B0001. 
Second chance exception 0xE0434F4D (Unknown) occurred in "KERNELBASE.DLL" at address 0x75B29617.
```

It seems that the application is loading a .Net 2.0 reference library although .Net 3.0 (and 3.5) is installed on the machine:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0]
>   "Version"="3.0.30729.4926"
>   "CBS"=dword:00000001
>   "Increment"="4926"
>   "Install"=dword:00000001
>   "SP"=dword:00000002

Here are my questions:
1. Is it possible to trap this exception so that the user gets a graceful exit?
2. Is it possible to determine from my application the .Net framework installed on the target   machine (Besides reading the registry)?
3. Why does my application try to load a V2.0 file?
4. How can I verify that my application is indeed targeting V3.0?

***Update:***
Well, I've learnt quite a lot here, but my conclusions are not promising:
If you target your application to .NET 4.0 then your application might crash when running on a machine that lacks this framework.
The crash occurs on the first call from **pure C++ to a C++/CLI** function. There's no way to catch it as it occurs on the framework boundaries.
I've found a **workaround** to the crash: Assuming you have a pure C++ project called 'A' that consists of a A.CPP file that calls a function from a C++/CLI DLL called 'B'. Just add an empty file 'C.CPP' to project 'A' and mark this file to be compiled with /clr flag. This will make project 'A' a mixed-language project and instead of a crash you will get the following message box (which is acceptable):
[image]
Sad enough, if you develop using **Visual Studio 2012** Express, your target is [always .NET 4.x](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780602/compiling-c-clr-dll-in-vs-2012-targeting-net-2-0-introduces-indirect-dependency-on-net-4-0#tabs).
In other words, if you want your application to run on Windows 7 (Without additional packages) then you must develop using VS2008.

Comment: A .Net application targets the .Net Framework version specified in the [project properties](http://tabsstudio.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/setting-target-framework-for-an-add-in-to-net-framework-4.png). There's no way that an application targetting the 3.0 version will run against 2.0 or any other version.

Comment: As an aside, WPF 3.0 is really buggy. You should really use 4.0 or above.

Comment: @HighCore I did set the projects in the solution to 3.0 and the IDE does reflect this. I wonder if there's an external verification method.  
Using 4.0 will coerce my users to install additional Framework. It doesn't make sense to me that Windows 7 could not be used as-is.

Comment: a .Net application requires the .Net Framework. Have you users install it. Most people will already have it by now. .Net 4.0 was released 4 years ago. I'm not familiar with `C++/CLI` so I don't know what might be happening in that front. You can try using [`Fuslog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) in the problematic machines to further diagnose the problem.

Comment: It seems that the target is 4.0 regardless to the explicit setting see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780602/compiling-c-clr-dll-in-vs-2012-targeting-net-2-0-introduces-indirect-dependency-on-net-4-0#tabs. I do think that forcing the user to install .net 4.0 is a problem since it involves restart of the system.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the application is loading a .Net 2.0 reference library

This is entirely normal, the core libraries (like mscorlib) are still v2.0.50727 in .NET 3.0 and 3.5.

> Second chance exception 0xE0434F4D (Unknown)

You cannot diagnose an unhandled .NET exception with Dependency Walker, it doesn't know anything about managed code.  If you can't get a managed debugger to the machine then use [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798).

And improve your program so these crashes don't fail the program without a diagnostic message.  Write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and display or log the value of e.UnhandledException.ToString().  You'll get the exception message and the holy stack trace that shows you how your program failed.

Comment: I would like to catch the exception but it occurs when the pure-unmanaged executable calls the C++/CLI DLL file. The DLL doesn't get to be loaded and I don't think I can write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException in the calling C++ code, or can I?

Comment: That's not what the exception code says, 0xE0434F4D is the exception code for a managed exception.  But yes, if the very first call into managed code fails then you of course have no opportunity to subscribe the event.  Could be as simple as FileNotFoundException if the CLR cannot find the assembly, that's a show-stopper.  You need a debugger, DebugDiag ought to tell you *something*.